# Turning Pandas Dataframe into list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["200"], "0": ["miner"], "1": ["miner, manager"], "2": ["mining, dude number 7"], "3": ["marshall"]})
```

I'd like to turn this into a list of dictionaries with keys as the **"id"** repeated on **"value"** that are the values of each column `split by ","` if it exists that would look like an output:

```
list_dict_from_df = [{"id": "200", "value": [{"lower": "miner"}]}, {"id": "200", "value": [{"lower": "miner"}, {"lower": "manager"}]}, {"id": "200", "value": [{"lower": "mining"}, {"lower": "dude number 7"}]}, {"id": "200", "value": [{"lower": "marshall"}]}]
```

I'm currently using a brute force method inside a loop to do this:

```
d_range = range(1, len(df.columns)
d_out = []

for i in d_range:
   d_out.append({"id": code, "value": [{"lower": col} for col in df.iloc[:, i].str.split(',')]})
```

This gets me close:

```
d_out:

[{"id": 200, "value": [{"lower": ["miner"]}]}, {"id": 2000, "value": [{"lower": ["miner", "manager"]}]}]
```

However, I don't want the strings "miner" to be contained within lists but separated by "," and their elements each taken into an id values like shown above.

I prefer to find a non anti-patterns to DataFrame solution (not iterrows() type) if possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
from pprint import pprint

lst = []
for id_, g in df.groupby("id"):
    for _, row in g.iterrows():
        for cell in row["0":]:
            lst.append(
                {
                    "id": id_,
                    "value": [
                        {"lower": v} for v in map(str.strip, cell.split(","))
                    ],
                }
            )


pprint(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
[{'id': '200', 'value': [{'lower': 'miner'}]},
 {'id': '200', 'value': [{'lower': 'miner'}, {'lower': 'manager'}]},
 {'id': '200', 'value': [{'lower': 'mining'}, {'lower': 'dude number 7'}]},
 {'id': '200', 'value': [{'lower': 'marshall'}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way after reshaping your data such that id is `set_index`, then all the columns becomes rows with `stack` and using `explode` to get a row once `str.split` by the comma. Loop over a `groupby` indexes to get the expected output

```
d = [{'id':i, 'value':vals.to_dict(orient='records')}
     for (i, _), vals in df.set_index('id').stack()
                           .str.split(',').explode()
                           .to_frame(name='lower')
                           .groupby(level=[0,1])
    ]

d
[{'id': '200', 'value': [{'lower': 'miner'}]},
 {'id': '200', 'value': [{'lower': 'miner'}, {'lower': ' manager'}]},
 {'id': '200', 'value': [{'lower': 'mining'}, {'lower': ' dude number 7'}]},
 {'id': '200', 'value': [{'lower': 'marshall'}]}]
```

Comment: timeit df.T.to_dict().values()